# Unable to boot Ubuntu - stuck at GRUB command-line

Tags: grub2, uefi

I've installed Ubuntu 18.10 on a brand new PC. First off, I wiped Windows that was pre-installed on the SSD + SATA disk. I installed Ubuntu no issue whatsoever (not the first time I do so, anyway). Now comes the time to remove the USB (install) media and reboot. So far so good.

It reboots, and I get dropped to the GRUB command prompt.

I googled around and found that I could fix whatever boot issue I had by using a nifty tool called "boot-repair", from the LiveCD.

I did so, but I could not effect the repairs as boot-repair insisted that I close all package managers such as synaptic and so. Thing is, none were running, so well, I could not complete the repair.

Boot-repair has a nice feature that allows it to collect info and publish it. If you need, you can consult it: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MYhdHt8kb5/

Now, I know there's nothing wrong about EFI, secureboot (disabled), CSM (Asus' "legacy mode") as I managed to install Fedora 29 with the same exact bios settings, on the same disk (actually the same, re-formatted partitions).

Before switching with a heavy heart to F29, I tried Ubuntu Server 18.04.1, Ubuntu 18.10, Kubuntu 18.10. Same result the 3 times.

I'm not that familiar on how to fix Grub in any way, I hope that my link above gives anyone enough to help me.

Comment: I have a hunch that the partitions from Fedora are causing a problem. Have you tried deleting them?

Comment: F29 came *after* Ubuntu.. I tried installing Ubuntu, got stuck at Grub, then installed F29. I wasn't clear, sorry (Engl. is not my main language, apologies).

Moreover... 

As I really hate Fedora, nowadays, so I took a chance and installed Debian 9 in the off-chance that it'll work.. so it did, re-using the partition scheme I had with F29 (I did not wipe anything). So it's most likely is a Ubuntu issue.

Comment: To recap:
- Wiped Win10 pre-installed on pc
- Tried to install ubuntu 18.10, ubuntu server 18.04.01, kubuntu 18.10. All installed succesfully but stuck at Grub
- wiped disks, installed F29 : success
- formated filesystems but kept the sizing and layout, installed Debian 9: works (writing this post from D9)

Answer (score 0):

Solved: instead of burning the kubuntu 18.10 ISO to an USB key (dd if=$SOURCE of=/dev/sdh bs=4M), I burned on a DVD. Slapped the DVD in the PC, and voilà.

Weird, tho.... dd is such a reliable tool.